# Existe collections no TypeScript, como por exemplo, java?

Tags: typescript

Se não existir, qual o porquê de não existir já que a orientação a objeto no typescript é tão 'bem estruturada'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementado não, mas existe extensões como essa no link abaixo:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-collections
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Saberia me dizer o porquê de não ter implementado ?

Comment: TypeScript nada mais que um High Level de JavaScript, ele sempre vai ser transpilado em JS . E fazendo isso você pode declarar um array de objeto, que um dentro desse array tem um outro array de objeto. Mas JavaScript esta evoluindo, logo vai ter essa estrutura.

Comment: JavaScript não possui um tipo de dados array específico. https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections

Nesse link você vai ver o tipo de coleções: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Keyed_collections

Mas nenhuma vai ser uma Collections igual do Java, porém essa extensão promete trabalhar  transpilar para as coleções do link acima.